# missing default constructor while using templates

Tags: c++, templates

We have a problem using a class template which itself uses function objects in some of its member functions. The error message form the VS2010 compiler is:

> error C2512: 'SimpleFunctor::SimpleFunctor' : no appropriate default
>   constructor available

The downsized code to reproduce this is as follows:

**// myfunctor.h**

```
class SimpleFunctor
{
  private:
    SimpleFunctor( const SimpleFunctor& );
    SimpleFunctor& operator=( const SimpleFunctor& );
  public:
    bool operator()() { return true; }
};
```

**// mytemplate.h**

```
#include "myfunctor.h"

template< typename T >
class Test
{
  private:
    Test( const Test& );
    Test& operator=( const Test& );
  public:
    Test(){}

    void testFunction( T parameter )
    {
      bool result = SimpleFunctor()();
    }
};
```

**// main.cpp**

```
#include "HK_Template.h"

int main()
{
  Test< int > obj;
  obj.testFunction( 5 );

  return 0;
}
```

This examples produces the above error message which seems to be correct since adding the default constructor to class SimpleFunctor like:

```
SimpleFunctor() {}
```

fixes the error.

So the question is, why does the compiler not generate the default constructor?

Comment: +1 for a very well-presented question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you define any constructor yourself, including a copy constructor, the compiler doesn't generate a default constructor anymore.

(On the other hand, a copy/move constructor *is* generated by default if you don't provide one, subject to certain rules.)

Comment: Aw, I was just about to commit the very same answer! `+1` from me.

Comment: Exactly, and just to make things clear, this behavior has nothing to do with templates, it's a general C++ rule

Answer (score 0):

The compiler only provides a default constructor when you don't define
any constructors.  Since you've declared a user defined copy
constructor, the compiler won't provide it.

It looks like that only reason you're declaring the copy constructor is
to make it private, and thus disable it.  In that case, a better
solution might be to inherit from `boost::noncopyable`, which has the
same effect, but doesn't prevent the compiler from generating the 
default constructor.

Comment: Or alternatively [explicitly delete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions) the copy constructor.

Comment: @Als Which is only possible if your compiler supports C++11.  Not an option for most developers.